# Shortest path in matrix with obstacles with cheat paths

Tags: algorithm, path, breadth-first-search, shortest

First of all this is an assingment and I am not looking for direct answers but instead the complexity of the best solution as you might be thinking it .

This is the known problem of shortest path between 2 points in a matrix (Start and End) while having obstacles in the way. Moves acceptables is up,down,left and right  . Lets say when moving i carry sth and the cost of each movement is 2 . There are points in the matrix (lets name them B points) where I can leave this sth in one B point and pick it up from another B point . Cost of dumping sth in B point is 1 and cost of picking sth up from a B point is 1 again .  Whenever I move without this sth , my cost of moving now is 1 . 
What I think of the solution is transform the matrix into a tree and have a BFS applied . However that works without the B points .

Whenever i take into account the B points complexity comes to a worst case scenario N^2. 
Here is an example :

```
S - - -
- - - -
B - - B
- - O E
```

S = Start , E = End , B = B point to drop sth, O = obstacle
So i start with S move down down to the B point (2*2=4 points) leave sth in the B point (1 point ) move right right (2*1= 2 points ) , pick it up (1 point ) , move down 2 points = total of 10 points .

What i thought was build the tree with nodes every B point , however this would create a very dense cyclic graph of almost (V-1)*(V-1) edges which takes the algortithm in N^2 boundaries just to create the graph . 
That is the worst case scenario as above :

```
S b b b
b b b b
b b b b 
b b b E
```

Another option I thought was that of first calculating shortest paths withouth B points . 
Then have iterations where at each iteration :
First have bfs on S and closest B
have BFS on E and closest B 
Then see if there is a path between B of closest to S and B closest to E . 
If there is then I would see if the path is smaller than that of regular shortest path with obstacles . 
If that is bigger then there is no shortest path (no greedy test). 
If there is no path between the 2 B points , try second closest to S and try again . 
If no path again , the second closest to E and closest to S .
However I am not able to calculate the complexity in this one in the worst case scenario plus there is no greedy test that evaluates that. 
Any help on calculating the complexity or even pointing out the best complexity solution (not the solution but just the complexity ) would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There may be better by using the fact your graph is a grid, but without using it you can at least get a solution in O(n^2 * log(n)), if n is the side of the square, so O(V log V) if V~n^2 is the number of vertices. A hint for that solution: you can use a bigger graph, in which a node is a complete state of the original problem, so a pair (position, haveObject)...

Comment: Your solution is way worse than that in the worst case: if you have Bs everywhere you will try every pair of B points, you don't want to compute a shortest path for each of them, and computing all of them together from start (with Floyd-Warshall for instance) would also be too long

Comment: It is important to notice that it is never good to drop and pick up your item more than once. E.g. look at this: `S-b-b-b-b-E`, you would drop in the first b and walk straight to the last b before picking up, it makes no sense to pick up at the 2nd b and drop at the 3rd again. But the bs closest to S and E are not necessairily the best ones.

Comment: @gdelab I don't know any algorithm that computes distances more effectively in a matrix , so if you know one just name it . Your O(V log V) is exactly the shortest path problem where in the case of a very dense graph where as input you have the matrix (input is n * n = V) and building the dense graph is of computation V * V-1 ~ V ^ 2 . So with your computation logic it is O(n ^ 4 log(n ^ 2)) or else O(V ^ 2 log V) . Complexity is always porpotional to input .
Problem is validating a greedy test so you dont have to test all paths

Comment: @maraca That was implied i think , but it isn't great help .  I already mentioned that there is no greedy test for my approach.

Comment: is it mandatory to drop/pick on a 'B'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is a representation of a graph. Without the cheat paths it is quite easy to implement a nice BFS. Implementing the cheat paths is not a big deal. Just add the same matrix as another 'layer' on top of the first one. bottom layer is 'carry', top layer is 'no carry'. You can move to the other layer only at B-points for the given cost. This is the same BFS with a third dimension.

You have n^2 nodes and (n-1)^2 edges per layer and additionally a maximum of n^2 eges connecting the layers. That's O(n^2).

Comment: Just a clarification , total complexity using dijkstra (ElogV) edition is

Answer (score 0):

You can just build a new graph with nodes labeled by (N, w) where N is a node in the original graph (so a position in your matrix), and w=0 or 1 is whether you're carrying a weight. It's then quite easy to add all possible edges in this graph

This new graph is of size 2*V, not V^2 (and the number of edges is around 4*V+number(B)).

Then you can use a shortest path algorithm, for instance Dijkstra's algorithm: complexity O(E + V log(V)) which is O(V log(V)) in your case.

Comment: My input is N (V nodes) and not V nodes with V-1 edges , so the total complexity is again V^2 in worst case where every point is a B point just to create the graph.

Comment: Nope. Even in this worst case the typical node has one edge going right, one going down, one left, one up, and one going to the other node with the same (x, y) value but a different value for w. Each of them being counted twice, that makes 2*V nodes and 5*V edges in total (neglecting the effect of borders and obstacles)