# Shortest path in labyrinth

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Let us  assume that we have a labyrinth represented by a m * n array of char . Our task is to find the fastest sequence of moves in order to transfer a carriage from starting position E to finish position S.

Each element of the array has one of the following values :

S , meaning starting position

E , meaning finish position

X , meaning obstacle

. , meaning open space in which we can move

T , meaning teleport.
Each teleport is connected with all other teleports . Only the carriage can be sent through teleports , not the man himself. The man must later move to a teleport to get the carriage back.

Each time , a man can either move left (L) , move right (R), move down (D) or move up (U) . When a man moves with the carriage , each step costs 2 seconds . If a man moves without carriage , each step costs 1 second . The use of the teleport system costs 2 seconds in total.

Example :

The array is:

S . . .

. . . .

T . . T

. . X E

The optimal solution is :

Down , Down , Right , Right , Right , Down

The time cost is :

2 + 2 = 4 , for "Down , Down"

2 , in order to send the carriage with teleport. We continue without carriage.

1 + 1 + 1 = 3 , for "Right , Right, Right" . Note that each step costs 1 instead of 2 , because we move without carriage.We now pick the carriage again.

2 for "Down" . 2 because we have picked the carriage again.

Total cost : 4 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 11.

Final answer : Down , Down , Right , Right , Right , Down

With is the most suitable algorithm for the task ?

So far , I have  considered the posibility of using dynamic programming .This would lead to a O(m*n) solution though...

I also considered the possibility of applying some kind of Dijkstra , but I would need O(m*n) in order to create the graph...

Comment: Warshall-floyd algorithm is a popular alternative to dijksta

Comment: Well , that's true . However in order to create a graph , I will probably need m*n edges , which yields O(m*n) complexity...

Comment: Why do you think you can do better than *O(m.n)*? In worst case you may have to look at every cell in your matrix, and even the optimal path may have a number of cells that is like m.n/2, so generating that path would already take *O(m.n)* time.

Comment: Basically the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344504/shortest-path-in-matrix-with-obstacles-with-cheat-paths