# shortest path in a grid with a twist

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve a graph based problem , this is the statement:
I have to find shortest route from position marked (s) to position marked (S) [**Note** : *I marked S and E just for ease of understanding*]. Here is the catch in problem I can go only through cells marked `0` and cells marked `1` represents walls which are impassable. Also I have the option to `remove only one wall` if it fetches me a shorter route to exit. ***Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.***

Sample 2d grid:

```
[
    [0(S) 1  1  1  1   ], 
    [0    0  1  1  1   ],
    [1    0  1  0  1   ],
    [1    1  0  0  0(E)],
]
```

If the option of removing walls were not present I could simply use`Bfs` or `Dijkstra` to find the shortest route. This question has been asked here:
[here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151820/bfs-shortest-path-for-google-foobar-challenge-prepare-the-bunnies-escape?noredirect=1&lq=1) - they simple use full exhaustive search hich is very bad for large matrices and they focus on language based optimizations which is not a good approach to a problem.

[Someone asked it here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151820/bfs-shortest-path-for-google-foobar-challenge-prepare-the-bunnies-escape?noredirect=1&lq=1) - The accepted answer has the following approach to it:

- Run a breadth-first search starting at the prison door, to find the
  distance of each passable space from the prison door.
- Run another breadth-first search starting at the escape pod, to find
  the distanceof each passable space from the escape pod.
- Now iterate over the walls, and consider removing each wall in turn.
  You know the distance of each passable space from the prison    door
  and the escape pod, so you can immediately work out the length    of
  the shortest route that passes through the space left by the wall
  you just removed.

But I am not clear what does this(***so you can immediately work out the length of the shortest route that passes through the space left by the wall*** ) mean in 3rd step above.

Also is there any better way to approach it?

***Can it be solved by dynamic programming and not using graph at all?***

Answer (score 1):

I would just augment the graph a bit as follows: build a new graph `G'`, which is twice as big as the initial graph `G`. Each node of G' represents a state `(v, rem)` where `v` is a node of G, and `rem \in {0, 1}` represents whether you have already removed a node or not. Also add one extra node E_new

The adjacency in `G'` is as follows:

- all `(v, 0)`s (resp. `(v, 1)`s) are linked between each other just like in G (which is if they both have value 0).
- if v1 has value 0 and one of its neihbors v2 has value 1, add an edge between `(v1, 0)` and `(v2, 1)`
- `(E, 0)` and `(E, 1)` are both linked to `E_new` at cost 0. (if you don't use costs just remove 1 to the length in the end).

Your goal is now to go from `(s, 0)` to `E_new`, Dijkstra (so BFS in your case if all steps cost the same) should work fine in time at most `O(n)` where n is your number of nodes (not the side of the square). A* would go faster but is a bit trickier to implement. If you want the solutions without removing the wall to be preferred (at equel length), you have to pay attention to the order in which you do your BFS (nodes with rem=0 first).

This is very similar to (actually an instance of) [Shortest path in matrix with obstacles with cheat paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344504/shortest-path-in-matrix-with-obstacles-with-cheat-paths/43362995#43362995).

**EDIT:** 
The answer you suggested above has the same complexity, requires 2 BFS instead of 1 but on a graph twice smaller, so probably similar, plus another loop, so I don't know which one is faster.

> (so you can immediately work out the length of the shortest route that
>   passes through the space left by the wall )

In step 1 and 2, you've computed the sortest path between the source and each wall on the one hand, and between the exit and all walls on the other hand, without going through any wall. By adding these two values for a given wall node, you get the length of the path from s to e through that wall only. By iterating through all the walls (or at least a part of them if you do it cleverly), you get the shortest such path, which you can compare to the shortest (s, e) path without crossing any wall, to keep only the best one.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a small example for my method:
suppose your grid is just like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0]]
```

The nodes in it can be represented by their coordinates (1, 1), (1, 2), etc. 
The only edges that are present are (1, 1) to (1, 2) and (1, 1) to (2, 1), and (3, 1) and (2, 2) to (3, 2). Add a 3rd dimension rem to each node, that can take value 0 or 1. For each value of rem, if (i1, j1)->(i2, j2) was in the graph, you now have (i1, j1, rem)->(i2, j2, rem). For all edges  (i1, j1)->(i2, j2) that were NOT in the graph (because of walls), you now have  (i1, j1, 0)->(i2, j2, 1). Plus, in the end, (2, 3, 0)->E_new and (2, 3, 1)->E_new. You can run BFS in this new graph.

Comment: can you please explain it with a simple xeample.thanks for your response

Comment: which part ? my algorithm or the one you've found ?

Comment: algorithm you explained

Comment: also regarding algorithm that i found , your explanation made it little more clear to me but a small doubt in the grid that i gave above in example. if we consider the wall at row 2 column 4 [ 1 based index ]. suppose distance from `S` and `E` sum up to be min because that will not make a passable path. how can i identify such cases?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. This wall is not reachable from S without going through a wall, so the distance you compute between S and that wall without going through any wall (step 1) will be inifinity (represened as a very big integer BIG_VAL), so the sum of it and the distance to E (that you get from step 2) can not be the minimum, except if there is no path from S to E in 0 or 1 wall-crossing. You can identiy this case by checking whether your min path is of length greater than BIG_VAL or not.

Comment: that algorithm at step 1 and 2 says  to find the distance of `each passable space` from the prison door and escape pod respectively but you said 1In step 1 and 2 you've computed the shortest path between the `source and each wall` on the one hand, and between the exit and all walls on the other hand. what should it exactly be ? find shortest path from both ends to `each nodes` or find shortest path from both ends to each `passable nodes`?

Comment: I think that by "passable space" he means "wall that, if removed, makes a possible path", i.e. "wall not between only other walls", but you can just do it for all walls (anyway the BFS will compute the shortest distances to all reachable points in the grid, including walls and non-walls). That's how I understand it at least, and it does work like this in O(n) time.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i will try to code it and also try your suggested method . i will get back  here and thanks for your example :)